# Invoke Lambda function on button click in React

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-cdk

To start I just want to say that I'm really new to AWS overall (1-2 weeks). So I might not think correct from start.

I'm working on an app where I want to click a button in JSX and trigger a Lambda function that gets data from a dynamodb table and shows it in the UI.

I'm writing the infrastructure as code using aws cdk. How should I face this? Do you have any guides that I can follow?

Answer (score 8):

Welcome! Please have a look on this [guide](https://medium.com/@gulikholmatova/building-a-serverless-react-app-using-aws-lambda-dynamodb-and-an-api-gateway-f846696f34cd).

With AWS, it's a best practice to create an AWS API Gateway, which acts as your HTTP/HTTPS/API web server.

[image]

Within this API gateway, you can integrate  a Lambda function with a route (e.g. GET /users), where that Lambda function grabs the data from AWS DynamoDB process it as you wish and returns the output.

To integrate it with your code, you create an HTTP GET/POST request to the API gateway URL.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this guide!